# hector_slam Install Question

Tags: slam, navigation, hector-slam, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry for asking a simple question but I am new to using ROS and Linux and want to make sure that I install the package correctly to use. I am wanting to install hector_slam to use with a Tim 561 LiDAR, I already have ROS and sick_scan installed and working to be able to visualize the LiDAR data. After reading through the hector_slam documentation I found a line to use for installing the package shown bellow.

sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-hector-slam

When using this to install the package do I need to be within a specific working directory like the catkin work space I have made for my project? Also I have Kinetic not indigo so I should replace that with the word kinetic to install the correct version right?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/339970/hector_slam-install-question/) by [Aust](https://answers.ros.org/users/50084/aust/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2019-12-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First and important note, [hector_slam](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_slam) is a metapackage. It includes hector_mapping and related packages.

If you want to install a package or a metapackage you can use install from the source option. As you mentioned, you need to use your distro when you want to install a package

```
 sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-hector-slam
```

---

**Method 1:**
You can be sure about that you've installed the specific package when you use the 'from the source' installation method by simply cheking the installation folder of the packages.
So simply go to "/opt/ros/kinetic/share" folder by typing this:

```
cd /opt/ros/kinetic/share
```

if you want to list all of the hector_slam metapackage packages, you can list them with grep:

```
cd /opt/ros/indigo/share && ls | grep hector
```

---

**Method 2:**
if you want see the packages are installed or not, you can use `rospack find` command. It will give you the location of the package. For example type this to the command line,

```
 rospack find hector_mapping
```

But if you try to search directly **hector_slam**, it will say it's not installed. Because this command doesn't work with the metapackages. You can use this command to find your manually installed or created packges.

---

**Method 3:**
You can use the `roscd` command to go directly to the installation directory if the package is installed. For example:

```
 roscd hector_mapping
```

then type `pwd` to see which directory that you're in.

---

I hope this answer is satisfying for you. If you have any question about hector, you can ask as well.

**Note:** You can find other packages with typing it's name instead of typing 'hector_mapping'.

---

Originally posted by [ermanas](https://answers.ros.org/users/43196/ermanas/) with karma: 46 on 2019-12-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `apt install` part of the command indicates that this is installing the program system wide. So no, you do not have to be in any specific folder to use that command.

As for replacing the `indigo` part to `kinetic` or what ever else distro you might be using. Yes that is correct, replace the indigo part to kinetic.

---

Originally posted by [Reamees](https://answers.ros.org/users/36207/reamees/) with karma: 591 on 2019-12-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1